# Could not set localStorage for https URL from Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage

http://fartersoft.com/blog/2011/03/07/using-localstorage-in-firefox-extensions-for-persistent-data-storage/

I have set localStorage for the URL from Firefox extension using above link's code.

If I use URL as "**https**://example.com",showing error as

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "The operation is insecure."

Comment: Just tried it in Firefox 14, works fine for me. Are you using some other Firefox version? If note - please add the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Vales saved with an https:// scheme are isolated, so you can't access them from a location that is just http://

http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html

Comment: The question is about Firefox extensions, extensions can access any local storage object they want.